# What is the name of the optimization that removes self eliminating multiplication-division statements?

Tags: optimization, compilers

I have a compiler optimization which should be quite common, but I can not find a name for it, nor a reference that describes it.

Given an integer x, not known at optimization time, a known constant c and the following program

```
x_1 = x * c
x_2 = x_1 / c
print(x_2)
```

It's pretty clear that the code can be optimized to

```
print(x)
```

What is the name of this optimization? Is there a paper/book describing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Value propagation?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably most easily described as a two-step process. First a step of [Copy Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_propagation) to get

```
x_2=x*c/c
print(x_2)
```

followed by a step of [Constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) to remove the unecessary operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm not sure about the "Copy Propagation" step. Wikipedia states "replacing the occurrences of targets of direct assignments with their values", in your example you do not replace it with a value, but with a calculation.

Comment: A compiler may decide that recomputing a value is cheaper than storing and retrieving it (for example in a situation where no more registers are available). Here the decision is easy, since `x_1` is read only once.